# How to open about:blank in SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui

I tried

```
    let url = URL(string: "http://about:blank")
```

and

```
    let url = URL(string: "about:blank")
```

```
Button(
    action: {
        UIApplication.shared.open(self.url!)
    }
){
    Text("Tap here.")
}
```

But it doesn't work.

When URL is invalid or null, I want to open about:blank.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`UIApplication.open` does not natively support the `about:` URI scheme, which makes opening such URLs impossible. UIKit has built-in support only [for the most commonly used schemes](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplication/1648685-open).